# How to set up nginx rewrite rules on Heroku using Unicorn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, nginx, unicorn

I need to set a couple of rules in nginx config file. I'm a bit lost in how to do so. These are the rules.

```
if (-f $document_root/cache/$host/$uri/index.html) {
  rewrite (.*) /cache/$host/$1/index.html break;
}

if (-f $document_root/cache/$host/$uri.html) {
  rewrite (.*) /cache/$host/$1.html break;
}
```

My questions are:

- Where is located the nginx config file under a Rails app and how the file should be named?
- Will Heroku automatically read for it? I read about buildpacks for customized deployments but looks a bit complex for what I do need.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to any nginx config on Heroku.

You should use something like [rack/rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) instead.

You are correct, you don't want to use a custom buildpack for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Use nginx buildpacks e.g. https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack

You can configure your nginx in custom/